# Nth-of-type wildcard in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to change class at some elements in a table.

The expected behavior is, when you click a `<th>`, add a class in all his `<td>` (in his column).

I have this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.tabla th:nth-of-type(1)").click(function () {
        $("table.tabla td:nth-of-type(1)").toggleClass('on');
    return false;
    });
});
```

It's working properly in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HzLf/1/) with the first sibling.

Well, I want to make the same with all `<th>`, but I don't know how many `<th>`are in the table (it's a dynamic table.)

Is there any way to make something like `th:nth-of-type(x)`?

Comment: I don't know if "Nth-of-type wildcard" is the correct form to express it... if not please, tell me. (I'm not an english speaker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try jQuery ".on" method for dynamic objects, also you will need to look for the current th with the $(this) object and look for its children td's to toggle their class 'on'.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("table.tabla th").on("click", function () {
          ind = $(this).index()+1;
          $('td:nth-of-type(' + ind + ')').toggleClass('on');
       });
    });
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer, here you are searching for td under the clicked th. but user want to toggle class for td below the clicked th, it means td with same index as th.

Comment: This works like a charm ;) Thank you very much! Also, thanks for the ".on" method (I'm a really N00B in jQuery, these tips help me so much).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the index() like this:

```
$("table.tabla th").click(function () {
    $("table.tabla td:nth-of-type("+($(this).index()+1)+")").toggleClass('on');
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3HzLf/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said, I will choose @awavi's answer for his useful explanation, but this also works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("table.tabla th").click(function () {
    var x = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $("table.tabla td:nth-of-type(" + x + ")").toggleClass('on');
return false;
});
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/3HzLf/3/

Comment: +1 Thanks, this also works. I will choose @awavi's answer for the explanation, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I set it works using the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method of the `th` clicked element indentified by `this` inside the click function (index return a zero based value)

Code:

```
$("table.tabla th").click(function () {
    $("table.tabla td:nth-of-type("+($(this).index()+1)+")").toggleClass('on');
    return false;
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eBzYm/

Comment: Your jsFiddle is not updated... still with my code ;)  Anyhow, I try to replace my JS with yours, and nothing happens when I click...

Comment: !! My bad, was another version, updated the main version with the working code